# Ubuntu 19.04 login screen

Tags: login-screen

I'm the only user on the login screen. Upon hard booting after a freeze, my username used to be highlighted automatically, so I could login by only using the keyboard. Now, my username is no longer highlighted automatically, so I have to mouse-over, click, then type. Is there a way to have my username highlighted upon boot?

Comment: At the login screen, try hitting the TAB (or down arrow) key and see if your username is highlighted. If so, hit ENTER, then enter your password, hit ENTER again. Report back. If that works, I'll put together an answer so you can accept it, ok?

Comment: @heynnema, both TAB and up arrow highlighted my username. Thanks!

Comment: I need to revisit this. I've found that if I catch the login screen before it times-out and goes dark, I can hit enter on my highlighted username. But if I leave for a while and come back when the screen has gone off, if I wake up the screen, my username is no longer highlighted and TAB and arrow keys do nothing. I think I may just have to live with this.

Comment: I'm having the same thing on 20.04, it's annoying to have to click on username instead of just hitting enter and typing the password if I have stepped away while the computer boots. Did you ever find a way to make it not do that?

Comment: @dwllama getting to 20.04 actually fixed it for me. Although if I let the screen go to sleep, then I have to hit Tab and enter. So I'm not sure why that  happened previously or how I fixed it.

Comment: Clearly I just need to learn enough code to fix it in the source myself. XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

At the login screen, hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys, to select your username, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, enter your password, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, and you're in!

**Update #1:**

Create another user account, with an alpha name that comes after your own username. This way, one account will always be highlighted on the login screen, and you can move between them, if required, using the arrow keys, as above.

*To stop the system freezing, increase your swap to 4G. Your current swap could be on an existing disk partition, or in a /swapfile. Review/edit `/etc/fstab` for the swap mount command string. Search here on AU for the procedure on how to do this.*

Comment: Strangely, this does not work after reboot now. But it does work after logout. I have to click my username with the mouse after reboot still.

Comment: @ticotexas otherwise, just create a new user with a username that comes after your username, so that two usernames will appear on the login screen, and then it should work again.

Comment: I'm figuring it out a bit more. Sometimes if Ubuntu freezes up, I have to hard boot by holding down the power button, then press it again to start up. Then my username is not highlighted. I just soft booted normally and my username was highlighted. I will report back when I try hitting the first letter next time I have to hard boot.

Comment: @ticotexas freezing huh? That's not normal. Edit your question and show me `free -h`.

Comment: total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       2.1Gi       2.7Gi       190Mi       2.8Gi       5.1Gi
Swap:         975Mi          0B       975Mi (I don't know how to format this correctly)

Comment: You're freezing because your swap is way too small. Resize it to 4G. Swap could be on a disk partition, or in a /swapfile. Search here on AU for the procedure on how to resize it.

Comment: Okay, I will try to find out how. I just rebooted normally, and my username would not highlight by pressing any letters, tab, arrows, etc. Only the mouse would highlight it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ticotexas Did you ever create the extra user as I had suggested earlier?

Comment: I hadn't, sorry, but I just did. I haven't yet run into my username not being highlighted. I increased my swap, so maybe that will fix having to hard boot. With the new user, the arrow keys switches between them; the letter keys do not.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to `settings`, navigate to `details` tab and then to `users`. There you'll find `automatic access`.

Comment: I don't want automatic login, but I would like my username highlighted automatically on the login screen.